# Google Apps and Postfix

Tags: email, google-apps, postfix-mta

I have an email address "@example.com" through google apps that was able to receive emails up until I installed postfix (and tinkered with the config) on my digital ocean droplet with the same "@example.com" domain. I suspect the emails are now somehow being routed to this droplet instead of the google apps email server but I am not sure how route them back through google apps. For reference, the error I get when sending a test email from my personal account to my google apps account is below:

"Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain example.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table"

I can send emails from my google apps account without issue, but after installing and configuring postfix on my droplet they are marked as unauthenticated.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of digging it appears all I had to do was point the MX records on my Digital Ocean droplet to the google email servers per the 'Add MX records' of this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-gmail-with-your-domain-on-digitalocean